# Executing ng test chromeHeadLess fails in jenkins

Tags: angular, jenkins, npm, junit, karma-runner

I have a project in **Angular 9** and so unit tests with karma.
When I execute my tests locally, everything work fine but not in Jenkins.

My goal is to have the junit report to use in Jenkins.

In Jenkins I have the following error

```
10:03:47  + npm run test
10:03:47  
10:03:47  > dclic_frontend@0.1.0 test /var/jenkins_home/workspace/dclic_frontend_master
10:03:47  > ng test --watch false --code-coverage
10:03:47  
10:03:47  Node.js version v11.14.0 detected.
10:03:47  The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v10.13 or v12.0.
10:03:47  
10:03:47  Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.
10:03:47  
10:03:47  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
10:03:47  npm ERR! errno 3
10:03:47  npm ERR! dclic_frontend@0.1.0 test: `ng test --watch false --code-coverage`
10:03:47  npm ERR! Exit status 3
```

I increased timemout in karma.conf.js -> no effect

Here the **package.json**

```
{
  "name": "dclic_frontend",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --base-href /coa/",
    "build": "ng build -- --base-href /coa/ --output-path=build/dist",
    "build:prod": "ng build --configuration=production --base-href /coa/ --output-path=build/dist",
    "test": "ng test --watch false --code-coverage",
    "test:dev": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main --first-only --create-ivy-entry-points"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/common": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/core": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/localize": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/material": "^9.2.4",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^9.1.9",
    "@angular/router": "^9.1.9",
    "core-js": "^2.6.9",
    "ngx-spinner": "^9.0.2",
    "ngx-toastr": "^12.1.0",
    "rxjs": "~6.5.4",
    "tslib": "^1.10.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.800.6",
    "@angular/cli": "^9.1.7",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^9.1.9",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.12.43",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "^4.1.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.5",
    "karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.4.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "protractor": "~5.4.3",
    "ts-node": "~8.3.0",
    "tslint": "~6.1.0",
    "typescript": "~3.8.3"
  }
}
```

The **karma.conf.js**

```
module.exports = function (config) {
  config.set(
    {
      basePath: '',
      frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
      plugins: [
        'karma-jasmine',
        'karma-chrome-launcher',
        'karma-jasmine-html-reporter',
        'karma-junit-reporter',
        'karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter',
        '@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma'
      ],
      client: {
        clearContext: false
      },
      reporters: ['junit', 'progress', 'kjhtml'],

      junitReporter: {
        browserNoActivityTimeout:100000,
        outputDir: '../test-reports',
        outputFile: 'junit-report.xml',
        useBrowserName: false,
      },

      angularCli: {
        environment: 'dev'
      },
      port: 9876,
      colors: true,
      logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,

      browsers: ['MyHeadlessChrome'],
      autoWatch: false,
      singleRun: true,

      coverageIstanbulReporter: {
        reports: ['html', 'lcov', 'cobertura'],
        fixWebpackSourcePaths: true,
        dir: 'coverage',
        file: 'cobertura-coverage.xml'
      },

      customLaunchers: {
        MyHeadlessChrome: {
          base: 'ChromeHeadless',
          flags: [
            '–no-sandbox',
            '--disable-translate',
            '--disable-extensions',
            '--remote-debugging-port=9223',
            '--headless'
          ]
        }
      },
      captureTimeout: 210000,
      browserDisconnectTolerance: 3,
      browserDisconnectTimeout : 210000,
      browserNoActivityTimeout : 210000
    });
};
```

The polyfill.js

````
import '@angular/localize/init';
import 'zone.js/dist/zone'; // Included with Angular CLI.
```code
  "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/ngx-toastr/toastr.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "codeCoverage": true
          }
        },
````

And the stage in **Jenkinsfile** where I commented the post of the report for now.

```
  stage('Angular frontend Karma Test') {
          steps {
              sh 'npm rebuild'
              sh 'npm run test'
         }
         // post {
         //   always {
         //       junit 'test-reports/junit-report.xml'
         //   }
         //}
        }
```

I have no idea of the origin of this issue.

Comment: But the answer is right in the output of the angular CLI: `Node.js version v11.14.0 detected. The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of either v10.13 or v12.0.` It needs either `v10.13`+ or `v12.0`, but not 11.x

Comment: thank you it was the point!